# How to exclude string enclosed in braces {xxx} and empty string using regular expression?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a list of string, now I want to filter out the strings look like this: {xxxx}  and empty strings: "", " ", "  " ...

Please advice.

Comment: You should say what language you're using, and give sample input and output. (Regexes don't really have a "filter out" feature, though of course they can be a very useful *part* of your filtering logic.)

Comment: By the way, the term "empty string" refers specifically to the zero-length string `""`. I can see that you mean something a bit different, but I'm not sure *exactly* what strings you want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you:

```
^(?:\s*|\{[^}]*\})$
```

This regex matches strings that contain 0 or more spaces or something between opening and closing curlybraces.